# Where do I connect the drain for my new sink in this layout and why is it better in that point specifically?

Tags: plumbing

Which of the points 1,2,3 is the best to connect the drain of the new sink in the below picture?
The green pipe you see in the wall is a dry vent (it will replace the vertical grey vent you see in the picture)
The white pipes are 1.5" ABS and for the common section I would assume it is 2" (for now it is under the slab, I can't see it)

**To avoid breaking more floor I could run the drain for the new sink through the wall and land near the shower drain end and add a common dry vent there. Is that a viable option?**
[image]

In the end it will look like this
[image]

Comment: As long as it’s under 5 or 6’ to the vent it should be ok I am not a plumber but have don quite a few houses we always used 5’ but I think 6’ is code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a wye fitting on pipe # 3, run pipe coming off wye (45 degree angle) and use and 45 degree fitting to line up with center line of new sink,use a medium sweep to turn up  clean out tee and then 2x2x11/2 santee at proper height   Approximately 20” from floor of bathroom . Run vent up wall ,over and above finished ceiling and tie into new dry vent of same size or bigger

Comment: Hi Rasta, thanks for the reply
any reason for specifically choosing that point?